# How to create a contact from xamarin forms to android and ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, contacts

in my app i read a qrcode that contain contact data, code reading is done successfully but the problem is i don't know how to open the "add new contact" page on Android and iOS

i've googled it everywhere and found some nuget packages by James Montemagno and Others but the problem they are all depricated

Comment: you will need to do this in platform code and then expose it to your Forms project via DependencyService

Comment: @Jason would you please give me any help with coding or what shall i exactly do, unofrtunately i'm self studying, so i have no one to ask.
and thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/contacts, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785663/get-android-contacts-in-xamarin

Comment: Very Thankful for your help. will start my search from here